# How to call static method in another page from Master Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a page that contains a static method like this:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static string Aware()
    {
        return DateTime.Now.ToString();
    }
}
```

How I can call this method from a Master Page?

Answer (score 2):

`_Default.Aware()` as for any other static method

EX:

```
 public partial class About : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _Default.Aware();
        }
    }
```

Comment: sorry dear friend. I mean call this function in master page.how can I do this?in master page we have not access to page classes

Comment: Unfortunately I have not access to page class in master page.

Comment: make sure they have the same namespace or just add a using in the masterpage

Comment: dear friend I have no namespace in my pages :(